# How to force 'Date' value on HTTP POST Request in JavaScript/Ajax

Tags: date, header, xmlhttprequest, request, overriding

I'm trying to force the Request Header value for 'Date' Parameter in Javascript on XMLHTTPRequest object by using the following:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Date", "Mon, 04 Mar 2011 03:31:18 EST");
```

I need to override the default Date value as above in order to pass the authentication for using a service using the POST request.

But when I run this code in Firefox, I don't see the "Date" parameter being sent out as part of the HTTP request. Any idea on how to force the Date parameter with the desired value as part of the HTTP Post request in Ajax/Javascript?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is explicitly forbidden?

I can see [this jquery code](http://jsfiddle.net/DzHzD/) creating an additional header in the firebug net tab

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'POST',
  url:'http://fiddle.jshell.net/',
  headers: {'d':'abc'}
}   
);
```

Yet if I change the header from `d` to `Date` it disappears